# Changing date format in monthly archive in Views

Tags: 7, views

I created a view which summarise the nodes and displays them in a year + month block. The result looks like this:

```
március 2015 (26) 
február 2015 (12)
január 2015 (18)
```

I'd like to change the date format according to Hungarian standards:

```
2015 március (26) 
2015 február (12)
2015 január (18)
```

I tried to find the appropriate settings in date/time settings (`admin/config/regional/date-time`) without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the date format in summary of months, I had to create a custom template of views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php, lets call it **views-view-summary-unformatted--post-by-date--block-1.tpl.php** and place it in the templates folder of my theme.
In this template we can find `$row->link` variable which is need to be replaced with the correct value. For this sake I processed the `$row->created_year_month` varible as follows:

```
<?php
    $archive_year = substr($row->created_year_month, 0, 4);
    $archive_month = substr($row->created_year_month, 4, 2);
    $archive_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $archive_month, 1, $archive_year);
    $archive_date = format_date($archive_timestamp, 'custom', 'Y. F');
?>
```

Finally I replaced the `$row->link` with `$archive_date`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a template file of your view **Display output:** **views-view--view-post-by-date--block.tpl.php**

**Make some slight changes where row is printing in your tempalate file:**

```
         <?php if ($rows): ?>
        <div class="view-content">
         <?php 
   $output = '';
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$filter_link = date("Ym",strtotime("-$i months"));
$filter_display = date("Y F",strtotime("-$i months"));
$link = $GLOBALS['base_url'].'/post-by-date/'.$filter_link;
 $output .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$filter_display.'</a>('.count($filter_display).')<br>';

  }
print $output;
// print $rows; ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't the solution I need: As far as I see your code creates a monotone list of months (without the correct count of news items) instead of the list of months actually have any news. Meanwhile I managed to figure out a more suitable solution - see below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own date formats at `admin/config/regional/date-time/formats`.

If you have the locale module enabled, you can localize your formats at `admin/config/regional/date-time/locale`.

Once you've created your own date format, you can tell views which format should be used to render a date.

Answer (score 0):

To change the date from "***március 2015***" to "***2015 március***", you can follow the following steps:

- Go to path "**admin/config/regional/date-time/formats**"
- Click on "Add Format"
- In "Format string" field, add "***Y F***"
- Now go to path "**admin/config/regional/date-time**" and change the format for your date-type.

Please try this, it will solve your problem.

Comment: :( ...........this one  not working